# Get duplicate items of an array using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this array (it is an example) and I'd like to get the duplicate items and push it into another array.

```
let arr = ["17: Mega Sena", "16: Mega Sena", "15: Mega Sena", "11: Dia de Sorte", "11: Dia de Sorte", "16: Mega Sena"]
```

I tried to loop with `foreach` and  got this:

My code:

```
var counts = [];
arr.forEach(function(x) { 

  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1

});
```

Output:

[image]

At first sight this is exactly what I want, but I need to loop over it in order to isolate the indexes and values. The problem is I didn't get any index and I can't loop over it, since the length is 0.

Then I tried a second option, save the values as objects and push them into a new array. But in this case I only get the values and not the keys.

Codes:

1-

```
var counts = [];
var counts2 = [];
arr.forEach(function(x) { 

  let obj = {x: (counts[x] || 0)+1};

  counts2.push(obj);

});
```

2-

```
var counts = [];
var counts2 = [];
arr.forEach(function(x) { 

  let obj = {x: (counts[x] || 0)+1};

  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1

  counts2.push(obj);

});
```

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The result I need is to get how many of each item exists in the array and merge the duplicate ones. But I need to know how many there are, not just merge.

Comment: You can loop over counts using for(let k in counts){..} or you can get the  keys using Object.keys(counts)

Comment: have you tried to sort it first?

Comment: You're trying to use strings as indexes in an array.

Comment: @SQL Hacks it worked great. Thank you very much. If you want to edit it as an answer I'll be glad to accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `counts` object has strings as it's indexes. Use `Object.keys` to get a list of keys.

[image: screenshot of JavaScript console]

Answer (score 1):

`counts` should be an object, not an array, since the keys are strings, not integers.

```js
let arr = ["17: Mega Sena", "16: Mega Sena", "15: Mega Sena", "11: Dia de Sorte", "11: Dia de Sorte", "16: Mega Sena"]

var counts = {};
arr.forEach(function(x) { 
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1
});
for (key in counts) {
    console.log(`count of ${key} = ${counts[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this, first sort the array, then loop over it a take what you want

```
let arr = ["17: Mega Sena", "16: Mega Sena", "15: Mega Sena", "11: Dia de Sorte", "11: Dia de Sorte", "16: Mega Sena"]
var sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                                                 // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
                                                 // (we use slice to clone the array so the
                                                 // original array won't be modified)
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, friend. This code doesn't give exactly what I need, because besides to get the items merged I need to get how many of them there are and I also need to keep the non-duplicated ones. I followed @SQL Hacks and I got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is just fine, you just add another array for distinct values add push into that also if must.

```
var counts = [], dist=[];
arr.forEach(function(x) { 
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1
  var didAdd = counts[x]==1 ? (dist.push(x)):false 
});
```